# What makes certain android classes "must -keep"?

Tags: android, proguard

I noticed that the "template" `proguard.cfg` always contains the following:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
```

Why these particular classes and not others?

Is this the complete list of classes that must not be "optimized out" by ProGuard?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In short, those classes are in the proguard.cfg template because those classes can be declared in the AndrodiManifest.xml.

Consider this minimal application:

**CustomTextView.java:**

```
package com.example.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setText("The class name of this class is not important");
    }
}
```

**ExampleActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CustomTextView(this));
        Log.i("ExampleActivity", "The class name of this class is important");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".ExampleActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now, without the line

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```

in the proguard.cfg file, proguard might be tempted to rename `ExampleActivity` to `A`. *It does not know anything about AndroidManifest.xml though, so it will not touch the manifest*. Since the Android OS uses class names declared in the application manifest to start an application, the Android OS will try to instantiate `ExampleActivity`, but that class won't exist since proguard renamed it!

In the case of `CustomTextView`, it's fine for proguard to rename it to say `B`, because the name of the class is not important since it is not declared in the manifest, only referenced by code that proguard will update when it changes the class name of `CustomTextView`.

In one way or another, all classes referenced from the template proguard.cfg file can be declared in the manifest, so proguard must not touch them.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question and for providing such a great answer. +1 already and I plan to accept +50 your answer unless something surprising comes along. Now the follow-up questions: **`#1.`** Do I understand correctly from your answer that `-keep` also affects mapping too, not only "optimizing out"?  **`#2.`** If future versions of Proguard support AndroidManifest.xml, then `-keep` will no longer be required for the aforementioned classes?

Comment: **`#1.`**: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "mapping". If you mean "renaming classes", then yes, `-keep` prevents proguard not only from removing the class but also from renaming the class. If you by "mapping" mean something relating to AndroidManifest.xml, then no, `-keep` does not have any relation to `AndroidManifest.xml` at all, which is exactly why `-keep` is needed in the first place (see answer to #2). **`#2.`** Yes, if proguard would know about the semantics of AndroidManifest.xml (and how to modify it), then `-keep` would not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [`ProGuard Manual`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html). It states that `-keep`:

> Specifies classes and class members (fields and methods) to be
>   preserved as entry points to your code. For example, in order to keep
>   an application, you can specify the main class along with its main
>   method. In order to process a library, you should specify all publicly
>   accessible elements.

> Is this the complete list of classes that must not be obfuscated by
>   ProGuard?

If you specify `-keep` That doesn't mean a lack of obfuscation. It means that it keeps those classes in your code. Because ProGuard while trying to optimize and shrink your app, it might remove certain classes if they don't appear to be used. Don't take my word 100%, but that's what I read on some other SO post once upon a time.

> Why these particular classes and not others?

I would assume because those classes are pretty important. And as you can see most of them are classes that `extend` the ones you listed. If you specify an `Activity`, `Service`, or anything else you listed, you definitely wouldn't want it to be removed during the optimization.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for an answer that is specific to the particular **Android** classes I listed. For example, **what** makes `BroadcastReceiver` must `-keep`? Stating "pretty important" doesn't tell me anything...

Comment: Well, I'd say the reason for `BroadcastReceiver` may be that often times a `BroadcastReceiver` class will not appear to be used (via other Java code), but it is referenced in your manifest. Meaning it is used, but `Proguard` doesn't recognize that, so you must `-keep` it so `Proguard` doesn't remove it. I don't know any of this for a fact, that's just my understanding from reading the [`Proguard Manual`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#).

Comment: Thanks. I did read the manual but I still don't understand why **ADT** chose these classes to be there in the template `proguard.cfg`. The description for `-keep` reads: "Specifies classes and class members (fields and methods) to be preserved as **entry points** to your code." BTW, classes derived from those listed above are not only kept but are **also unobfuscated**.

Comment: I've used progaurd on my apps, and when I decompile the application and use dex2jar on classes.dex then look at the structure, my classes are obfuscated, including Activities and Broadcast receivers which are specified with `-keep`. Are you saying they are unobfuscated based on personal experience or based on what you read? I believe them being preserved as entry points means that the name of the class will not be obfuscated, but the contents of the methods are obfuscated. Though I may have a misunderstanding.

Comment: Based on personal experience (what I actually see in the output of my exported & signed APK), not based on what I read. I trust what you're saying but I still don't understand why this is. Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by **the output**? 2. I'm sorry. What **exactly** do you want me to explain?

Comment: The answer and details of Jakar are correct. By default, ProGuard removes (or at least renames) implementations of classes like BroadcastReceiver, since they are seemingly not used in the code of the app (ProGuard doesn't know about Android conventions). This would break the app, so you have to specify to keep such classes. ProGuard actually only keeps their relevant public API; the internal bytecode is still optimized.

Comment: After reading the answer by @Martin Nordholts I noticed Jakar's comment mentioning the manifest. So +1 for that. What confused me however was the use of "often times", "I would assume", "pretty important" etc. Also, quoting "`-keep` doesn't mean a lack of obfuscation." is not what I have observed when examining Proguard's output (mapping.txt, etc.). I think that Martin Nordholts got it right.